# How to short an path of an file so it can be used to link in web page?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to link an online available image using img tag but the path of that image is too long although it got inserted but it took a lot space in editor which looks cumbersome.

Here is the path of file I inserted :-

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="image" title="Makhan bada">
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That isn't a path to a file in the first place. If you want to use a path, then you need to save the data in a file to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image in a separate file, then use the file path in the `href` attribute.

```
<a href="/image/image.jpg" download>Download the image</a>
```

The `download` attribute will prompt browsers to download it, rather than opening it.